# if or multiples

Tags: php

I'm trying to look through a mysql stored state to see whether or not they match a condition my code is here:

```
$stater = $this->state;
if ($stater == 'WA' OR 
$stater == 'BC' OR 
$stater == 'CA' OR
 $stater == 'NV' OR 
$stater == 'AZ' OR 
$stater == 'ID' OR 
$stater == 'OR' OR 
$stater == 'UT' OR 
$stater == 'MT' OR 
$stater == 'NM' OR 
$stater = 'wa' OR 
$stater = 'bc' OR 
$stater = 'CA' OR 
$stater = 'nv' OR 
$stater = 'az' OR 
$stater = 'id' OR 
$stater = 'or' OR 
$stater = 'ut' OR 
$stater = 'mt' OR 
$stater = 'nm'){               
                 $division = "West";
               }
           else{
           $division="";
               }
```

It is returning west no matter what :\ I tried changing the ='s to =='s I've tried separating each or into its own brackets ex if( ($stater='ca') || ($stater='nm')) etc but still nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In mid you are starting to use the `=` assignment instead of `==` comparison operator. This error could have been avoided by using `in_array()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're using `=` instead of `==`, so `$stater` is always ending up as `'WA'`. That said, it may be cleaner to use an array and `in_array()` instead:

```
$west = array('WA', 'BC', 'CA', ...);
if (in_array($stater, $west)) {
    $division = 'west';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `==` or `===` for comparison.
Also, for your case this code will be more handy:

```
$stater = $this->state;
$states = array('wa',
                'bc',
                'ca',
                'nv',
                'az',
                'id',
                'or',
                'ut',
                'mt',
                'nm');

if (in_array(strtolower($stater), $states))
{
    $division = "West";
}
else
{
    $division = "";
}
```

Comment: CA is uppercase in your array

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using '=' instead of '==' in IF block.

PS. This code looks better:

```
$stater = $this->state;
$states = array('WA', 'BC', 'CA', ...);  //add all options

$division = in_array($stater, $states) ? 'West' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator is `==`, not `=`.

Setting a variable always returns `true`, so your line `$stater = 'wa'` will by default return true for that whole expression.

And have you tried switching `OR` to `||`?

Answer (score 0):

You confused `==` and `=`. `$stater = 'wa'` sets `$stater` to 'wa' and evaluates it as a boolean, always returning true.

Also, you should really consider a [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) in conjunction with [strtoupper](http://php.net/strtoupper):

```
switch(strtoupper($this->state)) {
case 'WA':
case 'BC':
case 'CA':
case 'NV':
    $division = "West";
    break;
default:
    $division="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an if statement you should always use two ==, not one =.  One = assigns the value, which makes it true.

However, in this particular case I would do something else:

```
if (in_array($starter, array('WA','BC',...))) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have `=` (set) confused with `==` (compare).

Regardless, I would likely use this in your situation, which is much easier to read and edit:

```
$valid_states = explode(',', 'WA,BC,CA,NV,AZ,ID,UT,MT,NM');

if (in_array(strtoupper($this->state), $valid_states)) {
    $division = "West";
} else {
    $division = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an unconventional answer here too:

```
if (stristr('WA BC CA NV AZ ID OR UT MT NM', $stater)) {
```

Is a bit compacter than the overspecific array/list check. And in this and other cases it's often sufficient to check against a list of allowed values.